# VBA como comparar 3 o mas valores

Tags: vba, comparaciones

He estado buscando la manera de comparar 3 o más valores en VBA y he estado un poco atorado. Cualquier ayuda que tengas lo agradeceré enormemente.
Este es el caso:
Con dos variables es simple:

```
Dim a as integer
Dim b as integer
a = 1
b = 1
If a<>b then True else False
```

Pero mi caso es:

```
Dim a as integer
Dim b as integer
Dim c as integer
Dim d as integer 'y así....

a=1
b=1
c=2
d=1

'Aquí quiero saber si cada valor es diferente. True si son diferentes, False si no lo son
```

Bienvenidas todas las propuestas!.

Answer (score 3):

Si los valores a comparar están en un rango, puedes hacerlo con una UDF:

```
Public Function COMPARAR(ByVal vRng As Range) As Boolean
Dim MiCelda As Range

For Each MiCelda In vRng
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(vRng, MiCelda.Value) > 1 Then
        'no es un valor único. Salimos de la comprobación
        COMPARAR = False
        Exit Function
    End If
Next

'si llega aquí es que cada valor es único
COMPARAR = True
End Function
```

Que ejecutada sale así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si tus valores son en tiempo de ejecución, y están en variables en tu código, utiliza un Diccionario. Un Diccionario es un objeto que te permite almacenar valores **únicos**. No puedes almacenar dos veces el mismo valor:

> [Estructuras de datos:
> diccionario](https://excelyvba.com/estructuras-de-datos-diccionario/)

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
Sub test()
Dim a1 As Integer
Dim b1 As Integer
Dim c1 As Integer
Dim d1 As Integer
Dim a2 As Integer
Dim b2 As Integer
Dim c2 As Integer
Dim d2 As Integer

a1 = 1
b1 = 2
c1 = 3
d1 = 4

Debug.Print COMPARAR(a1, b1, c1, d1)

a2 = 1
b2 = 1
c2 = 3
d2 = 4

Debug.Print COMPARAR(a2, b2, c2, d2)


End Sub



Function COMPARAR(ParamArray vValores() As Variant) As Boolean
Dim MiDict As Object
Set MiDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim ic As Long

For ic = LBound(vValores) To UBound(vValores) Step 1
    If MiDict.exists(vValores(ic)) = True Then
        'este valor ya existía. No es único,salimos de la función como false
        COMPARAR = False
        MiDict.RemoveAll
        Set MiDict = Nothing
        Exit Function
    Else
        MiDict.Add vValores(ic), 1
    End If
Next ic

MiDict.RemoveAll
Set MiDict = Nothing
'si llega aquí es que cada valor es único
COMPARAR = True
End Function
```

Esto en la ventana inmediato te devolverá:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Verdadero primero porque es cierto que el primer grupo de variables son todas únicas. Y Falso para el segundo, porque no son todas únicas.

Comment: Bien!. Parece que tengo tarea que hacer... Gracias por tu retro y te informo cualquier resultado..

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar `and` dentro del condicional `if` por combinación de variables y comparar `a` con todas las variables, `b` con todas las variables, `c` con todas las variables, etc. y recuerda que el `True` o `False` debes asignárselo a una variable para poder utilizarlo.

```
Dim A As Integer, B As Integer, C As Integer, D As Integer, respuesta As Boolean
A = 1
B = 1
C = 2
D = 1
If (A <> B) And (A <> C) And (A <> D) And (B <> C) And (B <> D) And (C <> D) Then
respuesta = True
Else
respuesta = False
End If
```

Saludos

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Esperaba encontrar una función que haga la vida más simple. Pero con esto funcionará...